# Omit relative pronoun

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns

Is this acceptable:

> The cat I see has a short tail.

Or is the “that” necessary

> The cat that I see has a short tail.

I don’t know why, but in past tense it sounds to me as if it was ok. Like:

> The cat I saw had a short tail.

And since the tense should not matter for this, I’d say it is ok to omit the “that”. But maybe this is also wrong?

Also I’d say “I” is the subject and “the cat” the object. But I’m not sure if this is sufficient to be able to omit the ‘that’.

Comment: You may omit the relative pronoun "that" in both of those contexts (i.e., "The cat I see..." and "The cat I saw..."). The simple subject of the sentence is "cat." The complete subject is "the cat (that) I saw," "(that) I saw) being a post-positive adjective of "cat," a restrictive clause that adjectivally modifies the preceding noun "cat." The direct object is "tail." The complete direct object is "a short tail." The subject of the restrictive clause "(that) I saw" is "I," the verb "saw," and the direct object "that," whether it's expressed or implied, said or not said but meant.

Comment: You're right, the tense has nothing to do with it. Relative pronouns may optionally be omitted from restrictive (=integrated) relative clauses, **if** they are not the subject of the relative clause. So _The cat I saw was black_ and _The cat that I saw was black_ are equivalent, speaker's choice. But not _The cat that saw me was black_ vs the ungrammatical *_The cat saw me was black._

Comment: The only reason you might consider using "that" in the first sentence is to clarify that you're not saying this: "The cat, I saw, has a short tail." (That is to say, you observed that the cat had a short tail.) But it's not really necessary.